# Debezium kafka test cluster for unit tests with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, vert.x, debezium

anyone using Debezium kafka test cluster for unit tests with gradle?

I have a Vertx gradle project and would like to integrate the debezium test cluster with my verticl kafka client tests.

My first issue if the imports, they don't seem to work. How do I convert the maven style test imports ? `<type>test-jar</type>`

The vertx kafka client has a sample test so I hope it works once I overcome the gradle imports.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
  <artifactId>debezium-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

this is not enough to get the right imports

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'io.debezium:debezium-core:0.7.2'
}
```

Is this test library documented somewhere?

Thanks in advance

G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'io.debezium:debezium-core:0.7.2'
    testCompile(group: 'io.debezium', name: 'debezium-core', version: '0.7.2', classifier: 'tests')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accepted it because it pass what I was asking but I cannot get kafka to start. getting errors with ZK.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have any examples for using the kafka cluster in unit test (gradle) ?

Comment: I don't use Gradle, but it shouldn't make a difference. Here's an example for using `KafkaCluster` in our own test suite: [KafkaDatabaseHistoryTest](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-core/src/test/java/io/debezium/relational/history/KafkaDatabaseHistoryTest.java).